# Multi-tenancy in react-admin

Tags: authorization, react-admin

Does `react-admin` support multi-tenancy, i.e. is it possible for `react-admin` to show a logged-in user only their own data?

For example...

- Alice may have her own posts under `users/Alice/posts`, and
- Bob (perhaps from another organization) may have his own posts under `users/Bob/posts`.

After Alice logs in, she can only access her own posts (all resources under `users/Alice/posts`). This feature https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authorization.html seems to only allow role-based access control **within the same organization**, which is very different from users (from different organizations) having their own data.

Comment: From what you describe, this is what happens in typical `react-admin`; if you have `users` it would return a `list` of both Alice and Bob. Let me use `ids` in place of names. As sson as a user logs in, you have access to `props.record.id`, store that `id` to `sessionStorage` and utilize it within a component that renders at this path `users/[id]/posts`. Include a route condition `<Route path="/users/:id">`. The idea is that Alice/Bob are not unique, using `id` might be a better implementation.

Comment: @MwamiTovi, thanks for the edits! I have renamed the title so the issue is clearer

Answer (score 0):

React-admin doesn't support multitenancy because this should be handled on the server side, not in a SPA.

Details and explanation: https://marmelab.com/blog/2022/12/14/multitenant-spa.html